# Notify about CloudKit Availability

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

## Overview

I would like to be notified when `CloudKit` is not reachable.

Possible scenarios when CloudKit might not be reachable:

- `CloudKit` server is not accessible
- Internet connectivity is not available.

## Attempts made so far:

- Observe `CKAccountChanged` Notification
- Observe `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChange` Notification
- Check `CKContainer.accountStatus(completionHandler:)`

None of the above approaches notifies when there the connectivity is lost.

## Questions:

- Is there a special way to be notified when `CloudKit` is not accessible or do we have to use `SCNetworkReachability` ?
- If `SCNetworkReachability` is to be used what is the URL to check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no CloudKit notification that alert user about an Internet connection lost.

You're right, in order to check the Internet connection availability you need `SCNetworkReachability`.

About `SCNetworkReachability`, there's no need to check your connection against any server. [This repository](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) has an implementation that allow developer to check agains a server o without it.